# App for custom Gmail push notifications

Tags: software-recommendation, gmail, notifications, email

Does anyone know of an app that can notify me of new emails in my Gmail in specific time intervals? I mean, I want to set up hour intervals when it is ok to receive notifications.

I have researched a lot and seen apps like pushmail, where you need to forward to another email address, but I wan't something that does not need my mails to be forwarded.

The app will need:

- Gmail IMAP connection
- Notifications on new mail
- Quiet periods (or else OK-to-notify periods)
- Custom notification sounds
- Nice UI ;)

Comment: I use [Growl](http://growl.info/screenshots). It does not have all the features you request, but it is supported by many well-known applications: mail.app, cyberduck, dropbox, twitter, transmission....

Comment: Can you use Mail? Turn off Push notifications and enable fetch, you can then set to fetch every hour, or manually (when you open mail app)

Answer (score 1):

Except for your requirement of setting quiet-times, one possible option would be [Google Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_mac.html).  Perhaps you could have a cron process that starts and stops Google Notifier at specific times?